# Unable to trigger a user defined funtion on a WPF Window Load

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, user-interface

I'm finding it hard with this issue in `WPF`.

I populate the dropboxes on this `WPF` form dynamically (from the tables in `SQL Server`). I've written a function called `populateDropBoxes` which i used to call on `form_Load` in `WinForms`.

Now in `WPF` i get the below error
[image]

I've also used the below in `Constructor`/`Window_Loaded`/`Window_ContentRendered` but yet get the same error.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => { populateDropBoxes(); }));
```

NB: When i call `populateDropBoxes`() from for Ex: a button click, it works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 'void populateDropBoxes()
{
Con.sqlQuery("SELECT strCallerName, ID FROM VEN.tblCaller");
                foreach (DataRow dr in Con.queryExec().Rows)
                {
                    IDCaller.Items.Add(new ComboBoxes(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString()));
                }
}

**NB: IDCaller is the name of a comboBox**
       **ComboBoxes is my own class which has a Display & a Hidden Value attributes**

Comment: Is the `Con` connection object created?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Good shout!!! I had to initiate the Con object and it worked fine.Thank you ever so much.